# Formula with string

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

I'm trying to do a loop based on the name of my TextBox. For example, I have for TextBox the following names txtRA1, txtRA2, txtRA3, txtRA4. I want to put an i as integer in the local of their number. How can I do that? Is there any way? The code is next: ---> "Userform3.txtRA&i.Text"

```
Private Sub btGerarRelatorio_Click()
    Dim tWB As Workbook, aWB As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer, k As Integer, nr As Integer, v As Integer
    Dim A() As String, filename As String
    Set tWB = ThisWorkbook
    filename = Auxiliar.Range("bd_alunos")
    Workbooks.Open filename, Password:="***"
    Set aWB = ActiveWorkbook
    ReDim A(6) As String
    aWB.Worksheets("BD_Alunos").Activate
    nr = aWB.Worksheets("BD_Alunos").Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns("B:B")) - 1
    For i = 1 To 4
        For k = 1 To nr
            If aWB.Worksheets("BD_Alunos").Range("B5").Offset(k, 1) = ***UserForm3.txtRA&i.text*** Then
                A(1) = aWB.Worksheets("BD_Alunos").Range("B5").Offset(k, 2)
                A(2) = aWB.Worksheets("BD_Alunos").Range("B5").Offset(k, 3)
                A(3) = aWB.Worksheets("BD_Alunos").Range("B5").Offset(k, 47)
                A(4) = aWB.Worksheets("BD_Alunos").Range("B5").Offset(k, 48)
                A(5) = aWB.Worksheets("BD_Alunos").Range("B5").Offset(k, 49)
                A(6) = aWB.Worksheets("BD_Alunos").Range("B5").Offset(k, 50)
                v = 1
            End If

            If verific = 1 Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next k
    Next i

    aWB.Close Savechanges:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Userform3.Controls("txtRA"&i).Text`